# Are there any hypothetical FTL drives with a near-zero net energy loss in optimal conditions?

Tags: science-fiction, faster-than-light

A hypothetical FTL drive that I have imagined takes energy to enter FTL state, but almost all of the energy is retrieved once exiting that state. This way energy requirements will be low enough to enable casual interstellar travel present in softer sci-fi.

The "optimal conditions" would mean: engine as good as new and no large obstacles in the way.

My question: Are there any hypothetical forms of FTL drive with this characteristic?

Comment: Are we supposed to choose from the ones currently available?  How will we tell which hand-waved concept is "hardest"?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We prefer well defined questions which can get measurable answers. How do you measure handwaving on a, as of today, physically impossible technology? Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand what we expect.

Comment: Nothing is 100% efficient.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I was unable to determine a metric to measure handwaving. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Draco18s That's why I added "optimal conditions", although I have decided to say "near-zero" instead.

Comment: Generally, users are encouraged to wait 24-48 hours or more so that more would-be answerers have the chance to read your question and offer an answer. People on this site are scattered around the world and sometimes even have jobs, so you're not guaranteed to get the best possible answer in just an hour!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I envision this like a [regenerative brake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_brake).

You could have something like this using a 4th spatial dimension to skip across between sections of your own folded 3 dimensional plane.  You kick yourself up to a higher "dimensional potential energy" - sort of like you put energy into your train to get it moving, or get up to the top of a hill with your sled.  Then you reclaim that energy when you slide down the hill or put on your regenerative brake.

This might have fun narrative twists.  For example Draco18 wags his learned finger at you, reminding you "no such thing as a free lunch".  You get back the energy you put in, minus your tribute to the god Entropy.   Except -  if you slide down the hill to a place lower than where you started, you might reclaim more energy than you put in.  Possibly substantially more.

Comment: Make sure your brakes work well, or the returning energy might cause quite an impressive boom...

Comment: Another possible side effect of this approach: If that higher three-dimensional plane happens to have pre-existing matter in it, pulling that matter into our plane could be a source of free energy.

Comment: "Reclaiming" more energy than you expended could be hazardous, too.  Imagine very, very LARGE supercapacitors that get charged way past their voltage safety margins.  All kinds of high-voltage arcs in the engineering spaces, this would resemble something from a Doc Smith novel ("Solid silver bus bars as thick as a big man's thigh glowed red and softened from the ohmic heating as the gargantuan current flowed into the accumulators.")

Comment: The "Skaidon Warps" in Neil Asher's "Polity" series can be either net energy sources or sinks. Energy source warp stations need vast superconducting heatsink networks to remove excess energy from incoming people and cargo. The start of one of the stories in the series involves a failure of the energy buffers, and someone ends up stepping out of the warp travelling at a significant fraction of the speed of light... quite bad news on a planetary surface.

Comment: One possible element is that the energy may *potentially* be recovered, but doing so requires equipment that may be a tradeoff with vessel mission. Say, for instance, the energy recovery requires a large, delicate array and takes time. For a long-range explorer, where they're expected to be as self-sufficient as possible, or a cargo hauler where they want to reduce costs as much as possible, that might be okay. A fast courier or a military ship, where they don't have time to screw around with that, might accept the energy loss.

Comment: Note that  energy conservation and difference in gravitational potential energy has a lot to say about this sort of thing. Even a small distance (eg from the radius of Earth's orbit to the radius of Pluto's orbit) has gigajoules of energy difference. If you move from here towards the galactic center or closer/further from the nearest spiral arm, you're probably going to need to dissipate exajoules of energy into something.

Answer (score 4):

Once you handwave out FTL and then handwave out thermodynamics, The handwaving for various flavors of the two combined conditions is pretty negligible.  So, I'd say that it doesn't really matter.

However, if you want a method of zero net energy:

One method might be to have the ship travel in some form of hyperspace where it can draw energy from something there.  Thus, if you spend long enough in hyperspace, you recharge whatever batteries you used to get there.  That, at least might not break thermodynamics.

Comment: You aren't necessarily handwaving out thermodynamics as long as the energy retrieved is "almost all"; 99.99% efficiency doesn't break thermodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

It is not "faster than light", but if you had (and its a big if) the Portal Gun (https://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Handheld_Portal_Device) you could have a sub-light drive that worked like this.

**Design**

Create the two portals facing one another across a room in your spaceship. Put a mag-lev track between them and start speeding up a train. As you speed the train up going in the -x direction the reaction force accelerates the rest of the spaceship in the +x direction. At this point you could have just fired the train out the back like a jet plume.

But, because of the portals, you don't loose the train. It is still their going through your ship again and again. (repeating the same length of track). When you want to stop all the kinetic energy and momentum you put in is still their waiting to be harvested back out. (Minus losses, which would be significant but could be made lower if your train went through a vacuum).

This is sub-light. You would have to handwave something extra to make the concept FTL. (You also have to explain why they don't just use portals to get around, maybe the range is limited).

Comment: It's a nice idea, but I think it wouldn't work very well (for example, magnets wear out over time, turning might be inefficient) and, as you mentioned, isn't a solution for FTL.

Comment: The portals themselves, however, are a different story. As you also said, I'd have to explain why they don't just use portals to get around - but if we can instantly transport your train from one side of the engine to the other without net energy loss, we can do this with the entire ship.

Comment: You could if you had a portal gun, but if your portals were like the things in Stargate then you could not use them to move the entire ship other than how I have suggested.

Comment: The lack of FTL is a major downside, so too is the likely inefficiency/wear and tear. However I don't think the point on turning stands. Turning is really not an issue in space - why would you ever want to turn? Why didn't you just go in a straight line from A to B in the first place? (the chances of their being anything in the way you have to navigate around are negligible - doubly so if you are going between star systems). Even if you do turn it is exactly as bad (good) as any other Newtonian-thruster.

Comment: If the portals were like the ones in Stargate, it could even be more energy efficient and faster to disassemble the ship, push the pieces through the portal and reassemble the ship on the other side.

Comment: I just meant to say that "their is a set of portal limitations that would lead to this technology making sens". For example Stargate Portals that absolutely requite a cable connecting two of them to work - or have a range of only a few hundred kilometers.